# Is there a way to automatically clear filled out PDF forms?

Tags: pdf, forms

I filled in an online pdf form. After I finished, I closed the window thinking that the form will clear itself since I didn't save it.

When I went back to the website and clicked on the form again, it still had the information that I entered.

Other than manually deleting all the information on the form, is there another way of clearing the form?

Comment: It seems like cookies are saved in browser. You can set delete cookies after browser close.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the form itself, you can clear it via

```
Tools > Form > More Options > Clear form
```

Comment: This is no longer valid starting with Adobe Reader DC. The menu items are all different and There is no Tools > Form

Answer (score 1):

As long as you didn't save the form (as you mentioned), you can use the following command in Acrobat Reader:

```
File > Revert
```

Answer (score 1):

In Adobe Acrobat DC: Edit > Form Options > Clear Form

Comment: It is online, Adobe Acrobat DC isn't being used.

Comment: There is no "Form Options" menu item in Acrobat Reader DC on mac

Answer (score 0):

In the Adobe Acrobat App: View > Tools > Forms > Clear Form

Comment: Is this for a particular browser? Can you give us a screenshot?

Comment: This is for the Adobe Acrobat app. My apologies.
For an online form, I would clear the autofill data for that specific website. In extreme cases I would clear all the browser's autofill data and cache, then restart.

Comment: You can change your answer or delete this one and make a new

Answer (score 0):

In Foxit Reader: Form (tab) > Reset Form

Same thing in Foxit PhantomPDF